# How do I find the Blender api source code I would like to change in building folder?

Tags: python, development

I try to build Blender and have a customize matcap list.
I have already successfully change the default matcap to my own one. And now I wanna to add more on the list like the reference image below.

I changed the CMakeLists file in datafiles folder and build again but nothing happened.
I found that there is a entry called matcap_icon on Blender API document page.

https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html?highlight=matcap#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.matcap_icon

My question is. Is it possible to change? How do I find it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Questions about developing blenders source code are considered off topic here, only python addon programming is accepted. From a quick look I see three places that would need adjusting, `source/blender/editors/datafiles/CMakeLists.txt` `source/blender/editors/include/ED_datafiles.h` and `source/blender/editors/interface/interface_icons.c`

Comment: Thank you very much! It Works! And sorry for asking question in wrong place, I will be careful next time.